# Rust example List

Tags: rust

I have a class like:

```
#[derive(Clone,PartialEq,Debug)]
pub enum List<T> {
    Nil,
    Cons(T,Box<List<T>>)
}
```

Now suppose the Lists are created like the following:

```
let x = 
            List::Cons(0,
                Box::new(List::Cons(1,
                Box::new(List::Cons(2,
                Box::new(List::Cons(3,
                Box::new(List::Nil))))))));
```

Now I want to create a map function that applies f to each element in the List type but I have a problem because I do not know how to traverse through this data type.

```
pub fn map<T,U,F:Fn(&T)->U>(f:F,l:& List<T>) -> List<U> {
    let mut myList = List::Nil;
    if let List::Nil = l {
        return List::Nil;
    } 
    //Want to apply F to each element of l and than 
    // append it to myList but do not know how.
    return myList;
}
```

So something like:

```
let x = 
            List::Cons(0,
                Box::new(List::Cons(1,
                Box::new(List::Cons(2,
                Box::new(List::Cons(3,
                Box::new(List::Nil))))))));
map(|val| val+1,&x)
```

Should result in

```
List::Cons(1,
                Box::new(List::Cons(2,
                Box::new(List::Cons(3,
                Box::new(List::Cons(4,
                Box::new(List::Nil))))))));
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: Firstly, don't use linked lists: they're extremely hard to get right and have very poor performance on modern hardware. Now if you _really_ want to code a linked list, take a look at [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my own code so that is not an option.

Comment: There are no classes in Rust…

Comment: @Miiao object then.

Comment: @chen A map function should never take a function that takes a reference but instead one that captures the value - that's the nature of mapping and how iterators, options and results (every monadic type in general) work. Else you will have to clone every time you use the function, which is resource-intensive and no fun.

Comment: @chen, that’s definitely not an object… Why not to use match btw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a recursive struct, by far the easier way to work with it is by using recursive functions. They may be slow and you risk a stack overflow, but they are easy to write:

```
pub fn map<T, U, F: Fn(&T) -> U>(f: F, l: &List<T>) -> List<U> {
    match l {
        List::Nil => List::Nil,
        List::Cons(h, s) => List::Cons(f(h), Box::new(map(f, s)))
    }
}
```

It probably can be done using a loop, but I don't think it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this iterative approach:

```rust
#[derive(Clone,PartialEq,Debug)]
pub enum List<T: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug> {
    Nil,
    Cons(T,Box<List<T>>)
}

pub fn map<T,U,F:Fn(&T)->U>(f:F,mut l:&List<T>) -> List<U>
where
    T: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
    U: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    let mut my_list = List::Nil;
    let mut current = &mut my_list;
    while let List::Cons(ref v, ref next) = l {
        *current = List::Cons(f(v), Box::new(List::Nil));
        current = match current {
            List::Cons(_, ref mut next) => next,
            _ => unreachable!(),
        };
        l = next;
    }
     my_list
}
```

---

Or go with this totaly overengineered approach using the traits `Iterator` and `FromIterator`

```rust
pub struct Iter<'a, T>
where
    T: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug + 'a,
{
    list: &'a List<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T>
where
    T: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug + 'a,
{
    type Item = &'a T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        match self.list {
            List::Nil => None,
            List::Cons(ref v, ref rest) => {
                self.list = rest;
                Some(v)
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T> List<T>
where
    T: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'_, T> {
        Iter{ list: self }
    }
}

impl<A> FromIterator<A> for List<A>
where
    A: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    fn from_iter<T>(vals: T) -> List<A>
    where
        T: IntoIterator<Item = A>,
    {
        let mut head = List::Nil;
        let mut current = &mut head;
        for v in vals {
            *current = List::Cons(v, Box::new(List::Nil));
            current = match current {
                List::Cons(_, ref mut next) => next,
                _ => unreachable!(),
            };
        }
        head
    }
}

pub fn map<T,U,F:Fn(&T)->U>(f:F,mut l:&List<T>) -> List<U>
where
    T: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
    U: Clone + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    l.iter().map(f).collect()
}
```

Yes I had way too much fun implementing [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7530205178b7cd740e691bba98ed5259).